# How to execute four commands one after other using promises in node.js

Tags: node.js, promise

I am new to node.js , I am not sure why my below promises are not behaving as expected.

```
var command1 = sshCommands.init().catch( (error) => {console.log(error);});
    var command2 = command1.then(sshCommands.plan(filename, size, ipaddr)).catch( (error) => {console.log(error);});
    var command3 = command2.then(sshCommands.apply(filename, size, ipaddr)).catch( (error) => {console.log(error);});
    var command4 = command3.then(strap(filename, ipaddr)).catch( (error) => {console.log(error);});
```

Below are the functions that I want to trigger one after the other. Currently all are initiated at the same time. with the given code

```
module.exports.init  = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        session.execute('ls /opt/myFiles', function (err, code, logs) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve(code);
            }
        });
    }
)
};

module.exports.plan = (filename, size, ipaddr) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        session.execute('ls /opt/files', function (err, code, logs) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve(code);
            }
        });
    }
)
};

module.exports.apply = (filename, size, ipaddr) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        session.execute('ls /opt/files2', function (err, code, logs) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve(code);
            }
        });
    }
)
};
```

Comment: Because you must pass a *function* to `then`, just like you do pass one to `catch`.

Comment: Thank, understood the issue.. Just needed to pass a function as you mentioned. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing the point of promises in Node. The point of promises is that when one throws an error the whole set of them in invalid. So if you have [promise1, promise2, promise3] and promise2 throws an error promise3 will automatically not be executed. For NodeJS is suggest added a library like [bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird).

Either way your code should be done like this.

```
sshCommands.init()
.then(sshCommands.plan(filename, size, ipaddr))
.then(shhCommands.apply(filename, size, ipaddy))
.then(strap(filename. ipaddr))
.catch((err) => {...});
```

You can also do some evaluating on the things being returned from the fulfill.

```
shhCommands.init((e) => {
    console.log(e);
    return shhCommands.plan(filename, size, ipaddr);
}).then(...)...
```

More of the general promises [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then#Examples) or more on bluebird promises [here](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/then.html).

Comment: Not really. promise3 can be executed even if promise2 throws an error. Take a look at my answer for the example. Simply chain a .then to the catch of the promise rejection of promise2.

Answer (score 1):

I have simulated the test to make the promise chain work. See if it helps you.

In the fig 1.1, which is the test result, the first result is without using `await`in the call to `command1.init()` and the second is with `await`

Fig 1.1
[image]

```
// mochatest

    const command1=require('./init'),command2=require('./plan'), command3=require('./apply');
    describe("asyncTests", () => {
    it("handles Promise rejection",async ()=>{
        var filename, size, ipaddr
        await command1.init().then(function()
            {
                command2.plan(filename, size, ipaddr).then(function(){
                   command3.apply(filename, size, ipaddr); 
                })
                }).catch(function (error){
                    console.log("Error "+error)
                })
    })       
    });

// init.js

module.exports.init  = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject,next) => {
        //session.execute('ls /opt/myFiles', function (err, code, logs) {
        var v=false;
            if (v===true) {
                console.log("init"+v);
                throw new Error("init")
                //reject(v);
                next;
            } else {
                console.log("init"+v);
                resolve(v);
            }
        //});
    }
)
};

// plan.js

module.exports.plan = (filename, size, ipaddr) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject,next) => {
       // session.execute('ls /opt/files', function (err, code, logs) {
       var v=false;
            if (v===true) {
                console.log("plan"+v);
                throw new Error("plan")
               // reject(v);
               next;
            } else {
                console.log("plan"+v);
                resolve(v);
            }
       // });
    }
)
};

// apply.js
module.exports.apply = (filename, size, ipaddr) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       // session.execute('ls /opt/files2', function (err, code, logs) {
       var v=false
            if (v===true) {
                console.log("apply"+v);
                throw new Error("apply")
                reject(v);
            } else {
                console.log("apply"+v);
                resolve(v);
            }
       // });
    }
)
};
```

Answer (score 0):

@Vladyslav Kochetkov - promise3 can be executed even if promise2 throws an error. Take a look at this example. Simply chain a .then to the catch of the promise rejection of promise2.

[image]

However, if you cause a promise rejection due to an assertion error in the test (in the `catch` block of the `plan` call like so - `assert.equal("Error pln",error)`)

[image]

then `promise3` will not be called.

```
// mochatest
    const assert=require('chai').assert
    const asyncpromise=require('./asyncpromiserejection.js')
    const command1=require('./init'),command2=require('./plan'), command3=require('./apply');
    describe("asyncTests", () => {
    it("handles Promise rejection",async ()=>{
        var filename, size, ipaddr
        await command1.init().then(function()
            {
                command2.plan(filename, size, ipaddr).then(function(){
                   command3.apply(filename, size, ipaddr); 
                }).catch(function (error){
                    console.log("Error "+error)
                }).then(function(){
                   command3.apply(filename, size, ipaddr); 
                })
                }).catch(function (error){
                    console.log("Error "+error)
                })
    })    
    });

// init.js

module.exports.init  = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject,next) => {
        //session.execute('ls /opt/myFiles', function (err, code, logs) {
        var v=false;
            if (v===true) {
                console.log("init"+v);
                throw new Error("init")
                //reject(v);
                next;
            } else {
                console.log("init"+v);
                resolve(v);
            }
        //});
    }
)
};

// plan.js
module.exports.plan = (filename, size, ipaddr) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject,next) => {
       // session.execute('ls /opt/files', function (err, code, logs) {
       var v=true;
            if (v===true) {
                console.log("plan"+v);
                throw new Error("plan")
               // reject(v);
              // next;
            } else {
                console.log("plan"+v);
                resolve(v);
            }
       // });
    }
)
};

// apply.js
module.exports.apply = (filename, size, ipaddr) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       // session.execute('ls /opt/files2', function (err, code, logs) {
       var v=false
            if (v===true) {
                console.log("apply"+v);
                throw new Error("apply")
                reject(v);
            } else {
                console.log("apply"+v);
                resolve(v);
            }
       // });
    }
)
};
```